# can u do some logic in __init__ of a class?

Tags: python, class, oop

okay, some background, i was mainly using imperative and functional programming for last couple of years ... now i'm learning OOP and i feel that my code not following the best practices of the OOP paradigm.

```
class ImageBounding(Bounding):

def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, image):
    super().__init__(x, y, w, h)
    self.image = image
    img = Image.fromarray(self.image)
    self.text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
```

well i want text to be an attribute of any instance of ImageBounding but text depends on the value of the attribute image ... it's working but i feel the way i wrote this something is wrong.

please enlighten me if you know how to do this in a better way,

Comment: Why do you think it's wrong? About the only reason it might be considered wrong is if `self.image` and `self.text` are logically mutable, yet must remain in sync (in which case `text` might perhaps be better as an `@property` that is computed live; possibly cached and only recomputed if `image` changes).

Comment: Also, don't discount the (very real) possibility that `ImageBounding` should not be a subclass of `Bounding`, but rather be a class that *has* an instance of `Bounding` as an attribute (possibly derived from the image, possibly defined to constrain the image).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can*, but it might be better to minimize it. For example, the "dumbest" version of `__init__` would simply take an existing image and its corresponding text. A class method could be used to encapsulate the logic that derives text from the image.

```
class ImageBounding(Bounding):
    
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, image, text):
        super().__init__(x, y, w, h)
        self.image = image
        self.text = text

    @classmethod
    def from_image(cls, x, y, w, h, image):
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.fromarray(image))
        return cls(x, y, w, h, image, text)
```

Note that this is similar to how `Image` itself is defined; `Image.fromarray` is (probably) a class method like

```
def fromarray(cls, img):
    t = do_something_with_image(img)
    return cls(t)
```

This allows the creation of an `ImageBounding` instance to be easier (and potentially cheaper) for testing, without sacrificing the ability to create a "properly" configured instance in practice.

Answer (score 0):

while this works and as an example seems fine you could do either of the following:

1. just process the image outside of the class and pass it to the constructor afterwards or
2. create a private method to do the processing and call it from within `__init__`

   class ImageBounding(Bounding):

   ```
    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, image):
        super().__init__(x, y, w, h)
        self.image = image
        self.text = self._processed_image()

    def _processed_image(self)
        img = Image.fromarray(self.image)
        return pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
   ```